# Hiding a resource name in FriendlyID slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, friendly-id

I'm using FriendlyID to produce slugs for some of my models.

To use the example provided in the FriendlyID docs ( http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/frames ), my URLs currently look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/cities/seattle/restaurants/joes-diner
```

Given that in my case, a city wouldn't have anything but restaurants, I'm looking for a way to remove the "restaurants" bit in the URL, so that it would look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/cities/seattle/joes-diner
```

or if possible even

```
http://localhost:3000/seattle/joes-diner
```

What's the best way to achieve this - if it's at all advisable to do this? I can imagine that the last option might create some complications.

Comment: Have you looked at named routes yet? [Official doc is here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the fix to your problem in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing#controller-namespaces-and-routing

You can use `:path => ""` for this task.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Solution with specs and correct edit\update etc. slugs here:

http://jasoncodes.com/posts/rails-3-nested-resource-slugs#solution